# ICollection - check if a collection contains an object

Tags: c#, .net, collections

Knowing that the non-generic [ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't offer a `Contains` method, what's the best way to check if a given object already is in a collection?

If I had two `ICollections`: A and B and wanted to check if B has all elements of A, what would be the best way to accomplish that? My first thought is adding all elements of A to a HashSet and then checking if all B's elements are in the set using `Contains`.

Comment: Cast->ToList->Contains

Comment: @Nkosi you should probably put it in a answer so he can close this question :)

Comment: `My first thought is adding all elements of A to a HashSet and then checking if all B's elements are in the set using Contains.` So what happened when you tried doing that?

Comment: @Nkosi That's a much worse solution than the OP's proposed solution...

Comment: @Servy of course it worked, but I felt kinda strange about it. Um, why is Nkosi's solution worse than mine? ICollection's cast method casts the elements of the collection to a specified type (can I cast to object?) and packs them in a new IEnumerable collection that is returned. Is it the overhead of casting and creating a new collection (ToList) that makes it a bad solution?

Comment: @user5539357 So you have a working solution and don't have any problems.  So then why are you asking the question?  NKosi's solution would be performing N linear searches on a list, which will perform *much* more poorly.

Comment: @Servy It's not enough to stop at the point where things work, you need to learn more trying to improve a working solution.

Comment: @user5539357 If you want to code review your working solution, try Code Review, although trying to get a code review of your working solution *without providing your working solution* isn't particularly helpful.  Just asking people to re-create your working solution isn't helpful to anyone, and isn't the purpose of the site.

Comment: It is odd that Generic does have Contains.   Can you just use that interface?

Comment: Let's review. Problem statement: `bool F(A, B)` is true when B contains all elements of A. Algorithm given is: convert A to set, check to see if all elements of B are in A. Test case: A is {1}, B is {1, 2}.  Since B contains all elements of A, F(A, B) should be true.  Algorithm is: check to see if all elements of B are in A.  2 is an element of B, 2 is not in A, therefore, algorithm returns false.  Therefore algorithm is incorrect. Since you believe your algorithm is correct, **you have not tested your algorithm**.  Test it!

Answer (score 3):

> If I had two `ICollections` `A` and `B` and wanted to check if `B` has all elements of `A`, what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Let me rephrase your question in the languages of sets.

> If I had two sets `A` and `B` and wanted to check if `A` is a subset of `B`, what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Now it becomes easy to see the answer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Construct a `HashSet<T>` from `A` and then use the `IsSubsetOf` method to see if `A` is a subset of `B`.

I note that if these are the sorts of operations you must perform frequently, then you should keep your data in `HashSet<T>` collections to begin with. The `IsSubsetOf` operation is possibly more efficient if both collections are hash sets.

Comment: The primary reason you gain a performance gain when both sets are `HashSet` collections is that is that it makes `Contains` queries run in constant time.  You can gain this performance without constructing a `HashSet` from `A` if you call `B.IsSupersetOf(A)` instead of `A.IsSubsetOf(B)`.

Comment: @Brian: Good tip!

Answer (score 0):

> A and B and wanted to check if B has all elements of A

I think you have it backwards.  Add the B to the HashSet.

HashSet.Contains is O(1)
Overall it will be O(n + m)

Going to assume string

```
  HashSet<string> HashSetB = new HashSet<string>(iCollecionB);
  foreach (string s in iCollecionA) 
  {
      if(HashSetB.Contains(s))
      {
      }
      else 
      {
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Boolean ICollectionContains(ICollection collection, Object item)
{
   for (Object o in collection)
   {
      if (o == item)
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Or in extension form:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
   public static Boolean Contains(this ICollection collection, Object item)
   {
      for (Object o in collection)
      {
         if (o == item)
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

With usage:

```
ICollection turboEncabulators = GetSomeTrunnions();

if (turboEncabulators.Contains(me))
   Environment.FailFast(); //How did you find me!
```

Comment: This only uses reference equality and you might as well just use `collection.Cast<object>().Any(o => o == item)` if you want to do that.